# Popular input type de acordo com a Seleção feita no Combobox(OPTION)

Tags: php, input, combobox

Ao Selecionar um usuário no meu select preciso passar o que selecionei para os campos do meu formulário..abaixo esta meu metodo que pega essas informações.

```
public function LerDadosUsu(){
    try{
        $lerusu = "SELECT * FROM usuario ";
        $listusu = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($lerusu);
        $listusu->execute();
        $retDados = $listusu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $retDados;
        }
     catch(PDOException $erro_2){
     echo 'erro'.$erro_2->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

abaixo quero mostrar todos os dados do campo do usuário que selecionei no meu select do formulario

```
<div class="modal-body">
              <form  action="" method="post" name="frm_usuario">

              <div class="form-group">
             <label for="filter">Filtrar Usuário</label>
             <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>

             <select class="form-control" id="sel_usuario">
             <!--INICIO DA PESQUISA DE DADOS COMBOBOX-->
             <?php
             $objeto = new Usuario();
             $usuario = $objeto->LerDadosUsu();
             foreach($usuario as $usuario):
             ?>
  <option value=""> <?php print $usuario['nom_usujauport'] ?></option>

             <?php
             endforeach;
             ?>


             </select>
             <!--PESQUISA DADOS E RETORNA COMBOBOX-->
             </div>
```

á minha dúvida é como passar os dados que eu selecionei no combobox para os input type = "text" dos meus campos abaixo Nome: Email: Senha: Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco difícil de entender, tente escrever somente o necessário para que as pessoas possam lhe ajudar.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mas a duvida é como passar os dados do que selecionei no meu select para os campos, nome: emai: senha: imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso com uma ajax.
No seu select de usuários você vai usar o evento "change" para acionar o ajax. No value dos options você deve colocar o ID do usuário para utilizar o mesmo no ajax.

```
// AJAX
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#sel_usuario').change(function(){
        var id_user = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'arquivo.php',
            method: 'POST', // Default: GET
            data: { id: id_user }, // ID do usuário que você vai 
            success: function(response) {
                // Em caso de sucesso você vai pegar os dados retornados pelo Ajax e popular seus inputs.
                $('#nome').val(response.nome);
                $('#email').val(response.email);
            },
            error: function() {
                // Tratar os erros
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Arquivo PHP.

```
function getUser( $id ) {

    if ( is_null($id) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id =" . $id;
    $con = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($sql);
    $con->execute();

    $usuario = $con->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return json_encode( $usuario ); 
}
```

Comment: Fiz conforme Kaio Bruno mencinou acima...mas  não deu certo, poderia mencionar como faço isso nas marcações do meu HTML? exemplo como eu coloco o ID do usuário no option do meu  html?

Comment: Não cara, você fez diferente e errado, você não pode colocar uma função do PHP no onChange. Olhe o exemplo que eu fiz e compare com o que você fez, está totalmente diferente.

Comment: Se puder por favor mostre como faço isso no html...somente para método de comparação mesmo...Agradeço.

Comment: tudo que você vai fazer é no PHP e no javascript, igual eu coloquei no exemplo.

Comment: certo, obrigado!!